# Rails self-referential nested association not working with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am building a synonym dictionary app in Rails 3.2.13 where every word has many meanings, and every meaning is associated to many words.

Hence, in order to get all the synonyms for a searched term (e.g.'house') I would want to be able to do something like:

```
Word.syno.find_by_entry('house')
```

I tried implementing with a scope, like this:

```
class Meaning < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :words
  has_and_belongs_to_many :synonyms, :class_name => "Word"
 end

class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :entry
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meanings•
  scope :syno, includes(:meanings => :synonyms)
end
```

Currently, I can get synonyms for 'house', with code like:  `Word.find_by_entry('house').meanings.first.synonims`

However, when I ask for `Word.syno.find_by_entry('house')`, I get the word 'house' itself and none of its synonyms.

These are the generated SQL queries as reported by rails console, for that last expression:

```
1.9.3p286 :011 >   Word.sino.find_by_entry("house")
  Word Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `words`.* FROM `words` WHERE `words`.`entry` = 'house' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT `meanings`.*, `t0`.`word_id` AS ar_association_key_name FROM `meanings` INNER JOIN `meanings_words` `t0` ON `meanings`.`id` = `t0`.`meaning_id` WHERE `t0`.`word_id` IN (10112)
  SQL (12.9ms)  SELECT `words`.*, `t0`.`meaning_id` AS ar_association_key_name FROM `words` INNER JOIN `meanings_words` `t0` ON `words`.`id` = `t0`.`word_id` WHERE `t0`.`meaning_id` IN (1174, 3941, 4926, 7360)
 => #<Word id: 10112, entry: "house", changed_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

How should I write my scope to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong and Rails answer to:

```
Word.syno.find_by_entry('house')
```

is a nested hash with all `house`'s meanings and synonyms.

I tested this code in the Rails console and I was misled by the console's output, which only showed the response to the first query (i.e. the word 'house'). However, when I tested in my Rails application everything worked fine.

Nevertheless, I still must find out why the console's output didn't include the results of the last of all queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the word 'house' because that is what you asked for, a word that has the entry 'house'. I would take a two staged approach, kind of like you did with your "what works" example.

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :meanings
  has_many :synonyms, :through => :meanings
end

Word.where(entry: 'house').first.synonyms
```

This assumes that the word exists... In practice you would check for the existence of the word before calling for its synonyms.

Comment: No. I tried and I doesn't work either. I get the same results. I wonder why the last SQL query is built upon Word-Meaning association and not on the Meaning-Synonim association.